# Declined comment flag

Tags: discussion, flagging

A while back I flagged a comment, not because there was anything wrong with it but because I thought the moderators should read it and heed it: it collected a list of all the rapid-fire duplicates someone wrote of the same question (I think the comment was by Rebecca). I indicated in my message that I thought the moderators should merge the mentioned posts. The moderators then merged the posts. Why was my flag declined?

Comment: At least when I was a moderator, the way I remember it working was that the *only* two actions available for a flag on a comment were either to decline the flag or to delete the comment.

Comment: @ZevChonoles is correct.  The only options for the moderator when acting on a comment flag are "delete" and "dismiss," the latter resulting in the flag being declined.  Perhaps in this case flagging the question and directing the moderators to the comment would be the better option, but hindsight is often 20/20.

Comment: It would seem reasonable to add a "Dismiss with thanks" option.

Comment: @dfeuer: The intention of comment flags is that there is something _wrong_ with the comment itself.  In fact, sufficiently many flags on a comment causes it to be _automatically deleted_.  Furthermore you cannot upvote a comment you have flagged, and _vice versa_.  In this way, comment flags differ quite a bit from post flags.  [The more you know★](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/214632)

Comment: @ArthurFischer once the problem was cleaned up, wouldn't the comment calling it out be obsolete and be suitable for deleting?

Comment: @DanNeely: Yes, after the questions were closed and merged the comment would have been obsolete, and at that point it could have been flagged as such. But, again, at the time the comment itself was not the problem; the _question_ should have been the target of the flag. In truth, that comment should have only been made in concert with a flag alerting the moderators to the problem. The eight of us simply cannot scour the 450+ questions (or 1000+ posts) that are made _every day_ searching for problems that require our attention, or even comments directing us to such.

Comment: Isn't it the case that a flag may be approved when a moderator edits a comment but doesn't necessarily delete it? I flagged a comment twice with the suggestion that a superfluous insult be removed. The first flag was declined but the second flag was "helpful" and the superfluous insult in the comment was edited out (but the rest of the comment was preserved). So, does that mean that "dismiss" and "delete" aren't the only options? Or, is the case I'm describing special?